# Updating the View Relations field on Parse relations

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I have a book object and a author object and I want to associate the book object with the author object with a relation. My code looks like this:

```
var Author = Parse.Object.extend("Authors");
var myAuthor = new Author();
myAuthor.set("Name", "Dostoievski");
myAuthor.save();

var Book = Parse.Object.extend("Books");
var myBook = new Book();
myBook.set("Title", "The Idiot");
myBook.save();

var relation = myBook.relation("authors");
relation.add(myAuthor);
myBook.save();
```

But when I click on the View Relation field on the myBook object I don't have any data in the Name field of the relation. What is wrong with my code and what should I do?

Comment: open your console... is there a Uncaught You can't add an unsaved Parse.Object to a relation. error?

Comment: yes, that kind of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you have posted is exactly what you are running then you should have an

```
Uncaught You can't add an unsaved Parse.Object to a relation.
```

error in your console. This is the wonderful world of javascript and asynchronous promises. Before I keep explaining here is working code I tested in my console:

**Edit:**

The following is updated code. In the previous code I had tried to save the relation on the wrong variable. myAuthor and myBook variables were references to the new object your were creating and not to the resulting object which had been saved and returned by the promise. I changed the variables to be more explicit in what they are to help illustrate what the problem was. Below is working code.

```
var Author = Parse.Object.extend("Authors");
var myAuthor = new Author();
myAuthor.set("Name", "Dostoievski");
myAuthor.save().then(function(authorRes){
    var Book = Parse.Object.extend("Books");
    var myBook = new Book();
    myBook.set("Title", "The Idiot");
    myBook.save().then(function(bookRes){
         var relation = bookRes.relation("authors");
         relation.add(authorRes);
         bookRes.save({
                 success: function(relation) {
                     console.log(relation);
                 },
                 error: function(relation, error) {
                     console.log(relation + "::" +error.code+"::"+error.message);
                     }
        });
    });
});
```

Now, what is happening in your code:

```
var Author = Parse.Object.extend("Authors");
```

You now have a variable Author which has all the properties of the Parse Object you have passed the string "Authors" into.

```
var myAuthor = new Author();
```

create a new instance of the Author Class you just created name myAuthor.

```
myAuthor.set("Name", "Dostoievski");
```

You have set properties on the Author Class you have created.

```
myAuthor.save();
```

You have sent a request to Parse.com that it save your new object in the table you have created on Parse. In return Parse sends you a promise that will happen (but it hasn't actually happened yet).

```
var Book = Parse.Object.extend("Books");
var myBook = new Book();
myBook.set("Title", "The Idiot");
myBook.save();
```

Same here. You did all of the above and Parse.com has sent you a promise it will save myBook (But it hasn't yet).

```
var relation = myBook.relation("authors");
relation.add(myAuthor);
myBook.save();
```

Here you are trying to add a relation to myBook(but myBook hasn't been saved in Parse.com yet). **this is where your code breaks** because Parse does not allow you to create relations on objects which don't exist (because parse hasn't created an ObjectId for it to use to create the relationship).

To fix it, you have to wait until Parse tells you it is done saving your objects in the table and has created that ObjectId. To do this you add to your save() call...

```
.then(function(result){
   //now you can do things with the object you just saved. 

});
```

Comment: This worked fine without any erros this time :) but I still don't get any field updated on the View Relations field of the myBook object...
http://postimg.org/image/5h4vt3ahp/
The Name field of the relation shouldn't contain the value of myAuthror's name?

Comment: i'll take a look tonight

Comment: @IulianConstantinRedinciuc Sorry buddy, i have updated the answer with the correct code. please click check mark if all issues resolve. :-D

Comment: that works grate! but i don't realy understand the magic of the promise.... how dose it works and the role of the params bookRes and authorRes